# Azure Active Directory authentication and SAML

Tags: php, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, saml

I have running SAML plugin (which workes for sure - tested with other service) for my PHP web application.
However when I am trying to send SAML request to login.windows.net, it fails:

AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token.

Only this is showing..
How I can get inner msg of this error or what I am doing wrong?

I am using end points for Saml from my Azure, APP ID URI and name identifier "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistant"..

The APP ID URI is based on the active directory name (example): https://example.onmicrosoft.com/appname

Anyone can suggest me something how to resolve this?

Comment: Kamil, can you please paste the XML of the SAML AuthnRequest that you're sending to Azure AD? Can you also paste back the raw error response you're receiving (use fiddler to get the raw response). thanks

Comment: I updated my post with headers.. Honestly I have no idea how to get to the generated XML =P
I am using a plugin and all SAML data I am putting in the configuration of application.. heh maybe I missed something from requirements of Microsoft.. I have no idea.. I am trying to make this working since almost two weeks ^.^.. crazy!
anyway this fiddler is quite cool tool, but I didnt see that I can fetch there somewhere SAML XML..

Comment: haha You won't believe in this what was the issue!!
I was trying to log in with my admin credentials - that wasn't working, 400 error with trying to get token.
I added new user now and everything works!
Well, at least redirected me to the final point, now I will see what I am getting in SAML response.. ^.^
Thanks Dushyant Gill!